# How to change the group of the tasks added by third party plugins in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I added few plugins like pmd, checkstyle and findbugs in my gradle project. But they all come under group others.

Is it possible to create separate groups for them?

e.g. pmd group for tasks defined in Pmd plugin etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to configure task's `group` property. It could be done like so:

```
tasks.withType(Pmd).each {task -> configure(task) {
    group = "pmd"
}}
```

This snippet should be added to the script's root. It gets all the tasks with `Pmd` type and set for them all new `pmd` group.

Comment: can you clarify "script's root"? or share link were I can read more?  I seem to have to put it at the top of my `build.gradle` file but after `plugins`.  Thanks! 

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question which lead me here... I wanted to hide the **artifactoryPublish** task (from the Artifactory plugin) in the Gradle Tasks panel in Eclipse (panel is part of the [Gradle Integration Eclipse](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/blob/master/README.md) plugin). This panel has a toggle button to hide internal tasks, which by default will not hide **artifactoryPublish** because its *group* attribute is non-null.
[image: Gradle Tasks Panel - visible]

I tried using @Stanislav's code snippet for **artifactoryPublish** but couldn't get it to work (maybe I wasn't using the correct *type*?) Anyway, his answer pointed me to the [TaskContainer](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskContainer.html) and [Task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html) APIs though, which I was able to use since I did know the name of the task I wanted to hide.

This snippet did the trick:

```
tasks.getByName('artifactoryPublish').configure({
    group = null
});
```

After refreshing the Gradle Tasks panel the undesired task disappeared:
[image: Gradle Tasks Panel - hidden]